# slf4j and jetty conflict: SLF4J: Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND bound slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path, preempting StackOverflowError

Tags: java, jetty, slf4j

This error occurred when the slf4j dependency was added:
`implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:2.0.7")`

And in the line:
`org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server server = new Server(port);`

I have excluded `slf4j` everywhere where it might be, but the error still reproduces.

The dependencies (gradle.build.kts):

```kotlin
dependencies {    
    implementation("org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:$jettyVersion") {
       exclude(group = "org.slf4j")
    }
    implementation("org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:$jettyVersion") {    
        exclude(group = "org.slf4j")
    }
...
    implementation("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24")
    testAnnotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24")
    testImplementation("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24")
    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.7")
    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:2.0.7") {    
        exclude(group = "log4j")
        exclude(group = "org.slf4j", module = "log4j-over-slf4j")
    }
    
    configurations.all {        
        resolutionStrategy {            
            eachDependency {
                exclude(group = "org.slf4j", module = "log4j-over-slf4j")
                exclude(group = "org.slf4j", module = "slf4j-log4j12")
                exclude(group = "log4j", module = "log4j")
            }        
        }    
    }
}
```

Dependency tree:
`gradlew dependencies --configuration runtimeClasspath`

```
+--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:11.0.8  
|    +--- org.eclipse.jetty.toolchain:jetty-jakarta-servlet-api:5.0.2  
|    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:11.0.8  
|    |    +--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:11.0.8  
|    |    \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:11.0.8  
|    |         \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:11.0.8  
|    \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:11.0.8 (*)  
+--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:11.0.8  
|    \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:11.0.8  
|         \--- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:11.0.8 (*)  
+--- org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24  
+--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.7  
\--- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:2.0.7  
     \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-reload4j:2.0.7  
          +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.7  
          \--- ch.qos.reload4j:reload4j:1.2.22
```

## Additional info

Yes, I found several duplicates, but no one of them is the same. All solutions say to exclude `log4j-over-slf4j.jar` - and we can see that this dependency doesn't exist in my dependency tree and I already excluded all excessive.

Also, I made sure that `log4j-over-slf4j.jar` doesn't exist in the project folder. This jar exists only in the `.m2` folder.

Answer (score 1):

The message ...

`Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND bound slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path, preempting StackOverflowError.`

... is coming from your `org.slf4j:slf4j-reload4j` dependency.

[It is simply looking for a class `org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory` and if found, reports that message to you.](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/blob/5ccbe20b118828f35fd64a887d77fb9b72ad1a6e/slf4j-reload4j/src/main/java/org/slf4j/reload4j/Reload4jLoggerFactory.java#L46-L59)

First step, is to look for the class `org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory` in your dependency jar files.

Next step is to run your application outside of gradle.  It's not that unusual for various dependencies (esp logging) to come from your build environment itself (or it's plugins).

Alternate approach, don't use the deprecated log4j 1.x APIs.  Upgrade to log4j 2.x.  (the slf4j 2.x bridge for log4j 2 is available from the log4j group itself)